# is there any way to identify a code snippet in a text

Tags: code-snippets

A part of my project , I want to  the correlation of questions that contain a snippet of code(in any language) with duplicate questions. So is there any tool/API that can predict if a question in stack overflow contains a code snippet in the body.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are looking for it, but you can get the core dump provided by Stack Overflow and verify if the body of this question contains the "code" tag.

If yes, it contains a code on its body.